# assigning new function to ng-click reverted after refresh

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

I'm new to angular/jquery. I've a button which is used to refresh the page. I want to use this button for calling a jquery function. Tried changing the function where it calls the newly assigned function but get refreshed as well and everything get reverted.

Below is the original button:

```
`<button ng-repeat="button in formCtrl.getRefreshButtons()" class="btn btn-white btn-sm ng-binding ng-scope" type="button" ng-disabled="button.isDisabled() || button.isLoading()" ng-click="formCtrl.refreshButtonClick(button)" id="Btn0" style="">ImpData  </button>`
```

Below is the desired state of button:

```
`<button ng-repeat="button in formCtrl.getRefreshButtons()" class="btn btn-white btn-sm ng-binding ng-scope" type="button" ng-disabled="button.isDisabled() || button.isLoading()" ng-click="myFunction(e)" id="Btn0" style="">ImpData  </button>`
```

I've used the below lines of code to change the function assignment from
`` `formCtrl.refreshButtonClick(button) to myFunction():` ``

````
`$("#Btn0").attr("ng-click","myFunction(e)");` ```

ANy help will really be appreciated.
````

Comment: ng-repeat is angularjs, really do you want to use an old-fashion library instead of Angular? BTW to asing a function using jQuery you don't asign ng-click attribute else [`on`](https://api.jquery.com/on/) or [`click`](https://api.jquery.com/click/)

Comment: as i've mentioned, i'm absolutely a beginner, pls dis-regard what i've tried. it would be really helpful if you can elaborate your suggestion with the help of example.

Answer (score 0):

Can you change the behavior of `formCtrl.refreshButtonClick` to something like

```
function refreshButtonClick(button) {
  if (button.hasBeenClicked) {
    // call myFunction()
  } else {
    // your current behavior, plus
    button.hasBeenClicked = true;
  }
}
```

You're better off if you're able to perform all your actions within Angular, and avoid Vanilla JS's `onClick` etc on the side.